# Bringing Subview to front in custom UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, bringtofront

I am using a custom `UIView` which contains the following elements by default (after init is called these are set) :

- `UIImageView`
- `UIView`
- `UIView`

these are declared as `open var` in class code.

In my code I am adding another `UIView` like this:

```
myView?.addSubview(div)
myView?.bringSubview(toFront: div)
```

Now calling `bringSubviewToFront` works only on the div element which was added by code and not on the default views.

```
myView?.bringSubview(toFront: myView?.likedView)
```

How can I bring the UIViews to front?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code you have shown here. `bringSubView` does not accept optional value (view) .  `open func bringSubview(toFront view: UIView)`

Comment: is likedView initilized?

Comment: Have you made class for your myView & how is it added to your controller? Check if its child views are properly initilized.

Answer (score 3):

First clear the concept for `bringSubviewToFront`.

`bringSubviewToFront` can works only for direct subview or childview I mean you cannot do it for subview's subview.

For example you have view hierarchy like,

A -> B -> C

A is parent, B is it's subview and C is B's subview.

Now you can directly do like

```
 A?.bringSubview(toFront: B)
```

but can't do like,

```
 A?.bringSubview(toFront: C)
```

If you want C to bring in front then you have to do like,

```
 A?.bringSubview(toFront: B)

 B?.bringSubview(toFront: C)
```